# How to draw the stick diagram of a JK flip flop

Tags: transistors, design, flipflop, cmos

Recently me and my friends have been tasked a project to design a frequency divider using a JK flip-flop (divide by 4).

[image: the frequency divider]

After drawing the transistor circuit, I noticed that it was complicated for me to draw the stick diagram of one JK flip-flop let alone two. We were only taught to draw simple stick diagrams for for simple equations.

[image: the transistor circuit we came up with]

I can draw the stick diagrams for 3 and 2 input NANDs just fine, but I don't know how to connect them to each other in the stick diagram.

Comment: What's a "stick diagram"? I've never heard of it in all my years of electrical engineering.

Comment: Stick diagram - Just googled it and, it looks like a pointless abstraction of a circuit diagram.

Comment: looks more like an abstraction of how the semiconductor is doped and interconnected.

Answer (score 1):

For those who have not run across them, stick diagrams are a crude form of IC layout that emphasizes the order and placement of transistor gates, sources, drains, and so on.

The stick diagrams define individual "cells", such as the 2-input and 3-input NAND gates. The method of connecting the cells depends on the the target implementation technology. If you only have a single layer of polysilicon and a single metal layer then you would typically make the connections in a routing channel above or below a row of cells, using polysilicon for vertical segments and metal for horizontal segments (a Manhattan layout style). If you have two or more layers of metal then it may be possible to make horizontal connections directly over the cells themselves. (Usually the cells are abutted and assembled into "horizontal" rows, so when I talk about horizontal wiring I mean wiring that is parallel to the row of cells.